# Crashlytics stopped showing analytics for the latest release as well as crash free users

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

For years management at my company was getting "crash-free" users stats, and then in the latest release it just disappeared! We still get crash reports no problem.

Spent two weeks with Firebase support, trying all sorts of stuff, no change.

Adding launch flags to the app resulted in this message in version 10:

```
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Firebase Analytics SDK not detected. Crash-free statistics and breadcrumbs will not be reported
```

I'm at a dead end - did everything I was told to do, still no analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a special plist setting that would disable analytics, but it wasn't in the app anywhere. So to be 100% sure it was enabled, I added this code:

```
   [FIRApp configure];
   [FIRAnalytics setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:YES];
```

BAM! Now I see gobs of analytics messages in the Xcode console, and the warning disappeared!

Then I got suspicious and tried this:

```
    [FIRApp configure];
    (void)[FIRAnalytics appInstanceID];
```

That worked too. But why?

My guess is that their framework relies on the `NSObject` class method `+(void)initialize;` - the framework needs to get some message before iOS will send it to the class.

I spent a lot of time tracking this down, and hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like FirebaseAnalytics isn't being linked into the app when there wasn't a reference to it.

The more standard solution is to [Add](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/ReleaseTooling/Template/README.md?plain=1#L51) the `-ObjC` flag to `Other Linker Settings` in the Build Settings tab.

Comment: Well I can try that, but when I message it then it responds. Again, this implies it’s loaded but never gets an initialize message.

Comment: Hmm, `[FIRApp configure]` should initialize it, if it's there.

Comment: Well, my test proves otherwise. This with very latest Firebase Swift Package. I have an open support ticket on this issue and told them what I did to get it to work, but no response yet.

Comment: Both answers worked for me. I guess adding the API call also forces it to link the module appropriately. But the linker flag also works. Seems it was accidentally removed (We had the same symptoms, suddenly no Analytics recordings). Upvoted both 

Comment: In my app, this flag is not there, but everything worked fine until we switched to a package. After the switch, there were some FB messages in the console, so it was definitely linked in. The POD is a dylib loaded by the run time but Swift Packages are linked in at build time.