# Firebase/Google Analytics from iOS Stopped Reporting Suddenly

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

We have a iOS app that has Google Analytics integrated. It has been working fine for years, but recently suddenly stopped reporting completely. We thought the Cocoapods needed to be updated, but that hasn't made a difference. Looking at Firebase/GA4, neither show data coming in. We did not see anything outright that may have changed in Firebase or GA4 to have caused this, so confused.

Our Podfile is set up as follows

```
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'SwiftFormat/CLI', '~> 0.49'
  pod 'GoogleTagManager'
```

Any thoughts as to what we might look at to address?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124801/crashlytics-stopped-showing-analytics-for-the-latest-release-as-well-as-crash-fr/76130622