# Crashes register but no analytics info for Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I tested my Firebase analytics set up by forcing a crash using fatalError("Crash") for my iOS app. The crash is registered in the Firebase crash screen, but no analytics info appears when I am testing on an actual device. (If I am running in the simulator, everything works). That is, I can see my crash registered as having occurred with version 1.0.6, but the analytics info for that version never appears on either the Analytics Dashboard, Realtime Analytics, or Latest Release screens. It is as if that version of the app doesn't exist, other than under Crashlytics. I have waited several days, so it is not a latency issue.

There is a GoogleService-Info.plist file set up in the project and included in Build Phases under Copy Bundle Resources. I am calling FirebaseApp.configure() when the app starts.

I searched on Google and Stack Overflow for my scenario but don't find anything. I have used Firebase on other apps with no issue. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with swift and objective-c, shouldn't it be tagged with some firebase related tags instead?

Comment: Quite right. Sorry, this was one question that became another, and I forgot to change the tags.

Comment: can you share your firebase setup code in appdelegate or scene

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar, thanks for your reply. The call to FirebaseApp.configure() is the only setup code in AppDelegate.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76130622/556617